# Detect walls of text

Tags: feature-request, questions, formatting

I'm yet to see "wall of text" questions that were good, but I constantly see ones that are hard to read and make it really hard to answer.

A simple algorithm to detect "wall of text" in a question would be simple to implement in JavaScript. It would simply check "how close" something is to the word wrap limit and/or look at sentences that pass it. It shouldn't be hard to develop a heuristic around it.

It would be really awesome if Stack Overflow could warn people about to post "wall-of-text" questions about the potential formatting issue:

> Warning: Posting very word-dense questions makes it hard for other users to understand the question and post an answer. Please consider re-reading the question from the perspective of someone who never heard about the problem before and breaking it to paragraphs.

Or preferably, a better warning. I think that even if this catches 5% of wall-of-text questions it will help people browsing the new questions page.

Comment: How close is "close to the word wrap limit "?   Many people have different writing styles and organize their thought differently.

Comment: @ryanyuyu of course, I'm proposing we go for something that is _very far_ from anything reasonably readable. Also, I'm proposing a warning, not an error :)

Comment: How about: *" **Warning:** Unstructured heaps of text are really hard to understand. Please structure your question logically with paragraphs, line-breaks and other formatting as appropriate."*

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ah sorry, I misunderstood "warning".  If it's only a warning, anything more than say 7 consecutive lines without a line break would avoid being too annoying.

Comment: I think [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210448/we-need-to-improve-the-quality-of-our-spam/210452#comment675050_210452) puts it quite elegantly.

Comment: I consider these kind of requests rather odd.  Isn't it *nice* that you can instantly tell that the question is crap without having to slog through it and lose five minutes of your life?  Nobody needs this feature.

Comment: @HansPassant no one with a real problem comes to StackOverflow and _tries_ to ask a crap question. Walls of text take a lot of time to write, formatting is the easy part - phrasing is hard.

Comment: No one tries to read a crap question either.  Everybody is better off when it is obvious by ~20 to 1.

Comment: On a related note, questions that include unwrapped input data (eg, a big JSON object posted as a single line code block) aren't fun to read either.

Comment: @PM2Ring they're not, but there is a use case for copy-pastability I guess. If you have a concrete idea/proposal for those that'd be swell.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: True, and a newbie may not be aware of the facilities the language they're using provides for pretty-printing stuff, so it may be pointless telling them to fix it. FWIW, these days when answering (or commenting on) such questions (in the Python tag) I tend to reformat the ugly input data myself, or at least provide a link to the relevant function in the official documentation.

Comment: How about specifically checking for posts that have far more newlines than line breaks or paragraphs? That'd be likely to catch most of the people who *accidentally* create walls of text, by failing to hit enter twice for paragraphs and/or indent code blocks.

Answer (score 9):

While I think this would be reasonably difficult to detect well, I like the idea and I think it should be looked into.

Making people jump through hoops to get to a good level of quality may seem mean to some, but this is how we maintain a better level of quality for the community and the site.

I wish there was also a way to stop people cold if they have more than two 'i's in their text that are not capitalized properly. That seems to be a good predictor.

Comment: Well, note that this is not not adding another hoop here in the general sense. If you don't have 17 lines of grossly unformatted text we're not making you do anything in addition. This is merely helping a percentage of people who would have not gotten help anyway and saving the time of people who can avoid the close cycle. If this catches even 5% of wall-of-text cases I'm perfectly content with the time saved.

Comment: You are pretending like I argued with your point.

Comment: No, I did not. I also did not downvote your suggestion. I merely clarified my perspective as the OP on some statements you've made. Sorry if it came off as argumentative (not that arguments are a bad thing, it just was not the case here).

Comment: My answer was not a suggestion, it was an agreement with your question.

Answer (score -13):

I disagree with this feature request, because of two reasons:

- It would generate a large amount of annoying false-positives. For example, I would prepare a MCVE and copy it over. The moment I copy it, it will trigger a warning, because I need to indent the code by selecting it and clicking the button. Is this useful? No. Is it annoying? Yes, very.
- It will likely not help. The worst grammar and spelling seems to come from native English speaking people, who know how to write proper English. They simply don't want to write that way, omitting all capitals and punctuation. A warning will not stop them from doing that. For people that do not have English as the primary language, calling them out on that writing style will not magically improve their understanding of the English language. Most non-native English speakers do actually try their best to write understandable English, making it an easy edit if some things are not quite right.

Comment: Warnings are triggered when you click "Post your answer", not when you paste.

Comment: The warnings I have seen (mainly because of jsfiddle links and such) trigger the moment you paste them. I am not aware of any warning in the question/answer body that will only trigger on clicking the button.

Comment: Then you have simply not run into them, figuring out whether or not something is a wall of text _during the writing process_ is of course not something I'm advocating. That'd be ridiculous (as you point out).