# Unformatted code when formatting the uploaded pictures?

Tags: bug

I was formatting the pictures uploaded in my question. In my understanding there are two ways to insert a picture into paragraph:

`![picture1](link_to_picture1)`,

or another syntax which is what I prefer:

```
![picture1][picture1]
...
(At the end of my question)
  [picture1]: link_to_picture1
```

But the system tells me that the latter one has some "un-formatted" code in my description, and force me to do some 4-space indentation to nowhere, so I have to choose the only alternative: just in-line it.

I felt offended when I was trying to format it and came up with "un-formatted" warning.

---

### Edit:

I in-line the first link and update the formula1 and formula2 to no in-line and the same error appears again.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Detect walls of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300546)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second format is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
[![enter image description here][picture]][picture]


  [picture]: https://example.com/image.png
```

Notice that you are missing several sets of brackets (`[]`).

This is the format used if you use the Add Picture button on the editor too.

[image: Add Picture Button]

The identifier in brackets does not have to be a numeral. You can see the code attaching the picture above as:

```
[![Add Picture Button][aword]][aword]


  [aword]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wHzB.png
```

[image: Identifier]

Comment: Is that the `picture` can only be number? I change it with the format but the error appears again